# How to print subarray in smarty template?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty, associative-array

Following is my array title $test_data in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b
            [test_pack_name] => CPT General Economics
            [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains <b>16 chapterwise testlets</b> of 15 minutes each, <b>8 chapterwise tests </b>of 1 hour each and <b>3 full syllabus tests</b> of 1 hour covering syllabus of CPT General Economics.<br>
<b>Total Tests in this Package : 27</b>
            [test_pack_type_id] => 7
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 6
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => paid
            [test_pack_price] => 359.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_code] => 
            [test_pack_sold] => 0
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1338298119
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1343564534
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 0
            [test_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 580
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 581
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Micro Economics
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 583
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 582
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 579
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 578
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Demand & Supply
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 577
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 576
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 575
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Production & Cost
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 574
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 573
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 572
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Price Determination
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 571
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 570
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 569
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Indian Economy - A Profile
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 568
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Aspects of Indian Economy 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                )

        )

)

Now by using following statement I'm assigning this array to smarty template:

    $smarty->assign('test_data', $test_data);
```

Now I want to print the values of all tests in my smarty template i.e. I've to apply a loop for array `$test_data['test_details']`. I applied it but it's not working properly in smarty. Giving some vague result. I'm not understanding where I'm making a mistake. Can you please help me in this regard? My code is as follows:

```
    <select name="test_id" id="test_id">
                                                   <option value="all">All</option>


                              {foreach from=$test_data item=test key=key}
                          {foreach from=$test.test_details item=test_detail key=key}
                          <option value="{$test_detail.test_id}" {if $test_id==$test_detail.test_id} selected="selected"{/if}>{$test_detail.test_name}</option>
                          {/foreach}
                        {/foreach}   
                        </select>
```

Comment: Try naming your loops, `{foreach name = "outer_loop" [...]}` and `{foreach name = "inner_loop" [...]}` and see if it helps

Comment: What do you mean by vague result? Also which version of smarty are you using -- version 3 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

First: if you need to use the `key` variable in your loops, give it a unique name. You named both `key`. Also you're not even using that `key` so you might skip it altogether and leave just those `item` attributes.

Second: you're referring to `$test_id` and I don't see it defined in the code snippet you provided. If it's not defined elsewhere it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

please refer following code to access **subarray** in smarty template.

```
  <select name="test_id" id="test_id">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    {foreach from=$test_data key=key item=test}
        {foreach from=$test.test_details item=test_detail key=keylater}
        <option value="{$test_detail.test_id}">{$test_detail.test_name}</option>
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
  </select>
```